# Adding Website Search functionality in a site

Tags: php, laravel-5, full-text-search, web-search

I am developing a laravel 5.2 site, and I want to implement search functionality in it. Lets say of higher level, like search OLX.com uses.

I have tried mysql FULL TEXT Indexes but it doesn't give very optimized results.

What will be the best approach to do that? which method should i use?

Comment: try this link...http://www.webreference.com/programming/php/search/2.html

Comment: yes i have seen this, but this is a very naive technique to do that. using Like query doesnt work for me. there is going to a data in thousands may be more. So i need more efficient way to do this.

Comment: @NitinDhomse - that's both out of date and far less sophisticated than using a proper FULLTEXT index such as the OP has already tried. It might be worth giving Solr a look : http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Comment: Yes I am looking at this right now. but I cant judge is it good for me or not.

Comment: have you tried Elastic search?, which is very fast and optimized.

Comment: @NitinDhomse No i havent tried it. Which one will be easy and good? solr or Elastic? as I am doing this first time

Comment: I read somewhere that Google custom search is good approach. IS it for me? as I explained what I want.